# Upgradeng from iTextSharp 5.4.1.0 to itext7

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I am ugrading from iTextSharp to itext7 and not seeing `PdfStamper` or `RandomAccessFileOrArray` is missing `FilePath`. How can I use `RandomAccessFileOrArray' and what replaced` pdfStamper` ?

```
PdfStamper pdfStamper = null;
PdfReader pdfReader = null;
PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(FilePath,System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes("password")));
```

Comment: Please be aware that iText 7 is a complete redesign of the iText library. Thus, you won't get a one-to-one mapping from iText 5 classes and methods to iText 7 classes and methods. Before porting an application from iText 5 to iText 7, therefore, you should learn to use iText 7. The Jump-Start tutorial and the Building Blocks tutorial will certainly help, cf. https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do not have `PdfStamper` class in iText 7. There is only a `PdfDocument` class that is used for creation of files as well as for manipulation of files.

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));
```

Comment: What about the RandomAccessFileOrArray not taking in a file path?